# Question: Substrate vs Cosmos SDK

Tags: substrate-node-template, sdk

I need to gain some developer perspective on this if possible.

Essentially I'm trying to understand the following:

1. Are there any barriers to entry to use either of these? Or can any developer familiar with understanding of DLT fundamentals pick them up to kickstart their own blockchain?
2. Can you launch an independent project? Question specific to Substrate. In Cosmos you don't really need to enable IBC to connect to the larger ecosystem. Is this possible for chains developed using Substrate as well?
3. Will there be support for additional programming languages? Question specific to Cosmos SDK. IIRC Substrate pretty much supports all WASM languages.
4. As a developer, why do most people go with Cosmos SDK? Asking because I see more projects with it. Is it simply because of a first mover advantage?
5. What degree of flexibility is offered by both? That is to say, can a developer choose any consensus mechanism? Can one develop a POW chain? Can one develop a DAG? Naturally nether can support too much deviation and that's fine, what I'm curious about is whether you have enough tools to hit the ground running even when you take a non-conventional approach.
6. Can you develop a sovereign chain that doesn't need Polkadot's shared security? Question specific to Substrate.
7. If one launches a project and decides that they want to be part of the respective larger ecosystem. What are the barriers to entry for that.
8. How do both of these compare to SDK offerings from Horizen or Lisk?

Comment: Hey @Balthazar Wazowski, welcome! I like the title of this question, but it's far too many questions within that. Please refine a post down to one question for the community to provide an answer to, I encourage you to ask many around this topic! here is a primer: https://substrate.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: https://wiki.polkadot.network/docs/learn-comparisons-cosmos here is also a good start

Comment: and another one https://medium.com/@arikan/a-comparison-of-heterogeneous-blockchain-networks-4bf7ff2fe279

Comment: For general conversation, you might try this chatroom as well: https://matrix.to/#/#substratedevs:matrix.org

Answer (score 1):

*Answering question 1,2,4,5,6.*

1. Concerning barriers in substrate , one must know Rust (pretty advanced Rust) for easier start. But you can work with substrate using any other wasm compiled lang but that's bringing another layer of complexity because you need to implement the runtime logic and other low level types on your own language.
2. Yes you can launch an independent project (completely independent as you start with your own validators)
3. *no answer*
4. Why do most people go to cosmos sdk well there are over 200 projects building in substrate, and other pre deployed projects. And I don't know the number on Cosmos side.
5. Degree of flexibility, First you need to know substrate offers highest degree of flexibility. Every part is customizable (Consensus, runtime, transaction pool, networking) It just depends on your level of skills. But parts such as runtime and consensus are mostly customized. (Even the database layer and blocksize).
6. Yes
7. Did not understand the question, (which larger ecosystem?) If you mean bridges yes and with the help of XCMP and XCM you can tap in any other ecosystem.