# Substrate vs Cosmos / Tendermint SDK

Tags: sdk

Just one question.
Wny do we see more projects using the Cosmos SDK?

Does it have any particular advantages besides the first mover advantage?
As a developer, if you do prefer Substrate then what made you pick it over Cosmos SDK.

Comment: Hi @Balthazar ! The way your question is currently framed will yield opinion based answers which is not what Stack Exchange is for. Please try to reframe it and provide a clearer scope on what you’re asking, for eg: « what are the architectural differences » or « what underlying mechanisms are different ».

Comment: Please don't ask duplicate questions - https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/2271/question-substrate-vs-cosmos-sdk

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Question: Substrate vs Cosmos SDK](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/2271/question-substrate-vs-cosmos-sdk)

Answer (score 1):

1.Maximum flexibility

2.Rust lang

3.Ecosystem of senior devs

4.Cosmos has fewer modules and mostly they focus on Assets, but Substrate I can get the light if I want to build other than asset oriented protocal such as Phala network.

5.Gavin wood